# PHP assign value to empty element in array

Tags: php

I have a page with many fields a user can fill out. The fields are not mandatory but I do not want to sent a empty value to mysql as that will create problems later on. I'm trying to create a loop that checks if a variable is empty, and if empty assign some static value. Because I got rather a lot of field vars I want to do this without having to specify each field var.

```
<?php
$arr = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value))
        echo "$key empty <br/>";

    else
        echo "$key not empty <br/>";
}

print_r($arr);
?>
```

Shows all fieldname:empty or fieldname:not empty.

I tried adding various things such as `$arr[$key] = "TEST";` or `$key = "TEST";` below `if (empty($value))` but I cannot get the empty fields to update in the printed array.

Comment: Rather than using `get_defined_vars()`, it may be better to create an array with a list of all of the variables you want to check to ensure have some sort of value.  At the moment you may affect values used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You can also set default values for fields in MySQL itself. That might be smarter than trying to do this from your code.

Comment: Unfortunatly that won't work I think because my fields will just push an empty value into mysql. mysql for whatever reason won't allow default values on text fields either.